# Include imagen for label

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm developing on google apps and would like to place an image inside the button, it is possible?
For eg. put on my button this picture https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/searchicon.png

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add background-image property in css.

```
background-image: url('https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/searchicon.png');
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/matku/vdvpe/

in google apps script you can set css property using:

```
widget.setStyleAttribute(attribute, value);
```

so in your case it should look lkie this:

```
var button = app.createButton();
    button.setWidth("200px");
    button.setHeight("200px");
    button.setStyleAttribute("background-image", "url('https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/searchicon.png')")
```

Comment: Thank you for help me, my friend, But would it work on the script of google Apps?